# Design a button, android?

Tags: android, xml, button, textview

[image: BUTTON]

I need to design a this type button which should have a background with another small image in the center and the text at the bottom.

While the current I am using is a textview as below

```
     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

But i cannot put an image in its center.

If I use android:drawableTop
this is the image I get

[image]

How can this be feasible?

Comment: use imagebutton and textview aligned bottem to imagebutton

Comment: you can use compound drawables

Answer (score 1):

try compound drawables here is an example

```
<TextView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:drawableTop="@drawable/image"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/text" />
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put a bellow line to your TextView xml and change "img_src" to your image.

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/img_src"
```

**UPDATE 1 :**

`drawableTop` only support to draw above the text.

If you want to draw image on the center, here is a sample code.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_image" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/center_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: drawableTop doesn't centre the image.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one, works exactly as you want

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_my"
        android:text="SomeText" />
```

**btn_my.xml** // add this inside drawable folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

**copy the below into styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyButton">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff29549f</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Here is the **OUTPUT**

[image]